# Kendo UI treeview parent node without checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, treeview, kendo-ui

What approach will be to achieve displaying TreeView with checkboxs but I do not need checkbox for parents node only for "items" without children. i.e. I am displaying folder structure but do not want to have checkbox for any folder only for files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use use [checkbox template](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#checkboxestemplate-stringfunction). If there are not children do not display checkbox input at all.
[Here is a JSBIN example](http://jsbin.com/edamuj/131/edit) what I am talking about.

Comment: If anyone copies the code from the JSBin make sure to include the databinding for the checked state. Something along the lines of `#= item.checked ? 'checked' : '' #` which will conditionally output the checked attribute to the control.