# How to give checkbox only for parent nodes and not for child nodes in kendo treeview?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

// please do refer this below link and let us know the answer

Visit http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/checkboxes

Comment: No-one will answer this for you until you provide some of your own code that shows what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Nerdwood I don't think u need code to answer this.The question is so straight forward.

Comment: @Nerdwood body was necessary so I just appended some link that's it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847237/kendo-ui-treeview-parent-node-without-checkbox#new-answer. Check out this link .I need exact opposite of this .Means I need checkboxes for parent nodes and not for child nodes.

Comment: You didn't even show an example of what you wanted to achieve, and didn't show any code samples to guide us. That's why you were downvoted so much. But, it seems that the other SO post you referred to has actually answered the question, so I'll put together an answer based on it...

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted if it has worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show checkboxes next to parent nodes (e.g. folders) and not next to child nodes (e.g. files), you can use a [checkbox template](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#checkboxestemplate-stringfunction) as suggested in this related SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13848460/1805328

Just use a checkbox template of:

```
template: "# if(item.hasChildren){# <input type='checkbox'  name='checkedFiles[#= item.id #]' value='true' />#}#"
```

This creates an `input` of `type='checkbox'` only for items that have children.

Here's [the JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/fohibotece/edit?html,output).

Comment: Thanks:)Its working fine:)

Comment: yup sure:):)But I got down votes for this question:(

Comment: Yep, that would probably be because of the lack of detail given (I generally don't downvote, but that's usually the case). Still important to mark an answer to help others out.  :)

Comment: Ya thanks anyways :):)

Answer (score 0):

Use the code that you mention, but change the condition in the kendo template to display checkboxes only on nodes that have children : `template: "# if(item.hasChildren){# <input type='checkbox'  name='checkedFiles[#= item.id #]' value='true' />#}#"`

Example : http://dojo.telerik.com/ugOla

Comment: Thanks for the answer:)